# Assign New Leads of Existing Accounts to Account Owner

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

Salesforce - Apex Trigger for New Leads for Existing Accounts. How?

Hello,

I would like to write an Apex Trigger to check if a new lead's COMPANY or NAME already exists as an ACCOUNT, and therefore assign the new lead to the proper ACCOUNT OWNER.

Is there a formula that anyone can provide me to make this happen?

It would be great if the formula would look for CONTAINS "ACCOUNT NAME" rather than a direct match, for cases where a new lead submits their company name in a format slightly different than our existing ACCOUNT NAME.

Thank you greatly for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done with just a formula.  You will need a trigger, preferably one that calls an apex class to do the work.  The class will have to be without sharing if you want to reassign the owner id.  You'll have to query account for this.

Comment: I was able to write the trigger but we have a second business requirement which is: if a new lead is linked to two account records with different owners, route lead to user who will act as a "tie breaker," and manually assign the new lead to the correct user. I've created a secret gist in github to view what I've developed so far. The last two lines of the code are as far as I've gotten with the new business requirement. If you get a chance to take a look, I'd appreciate it: https://gist.github.com/jcamp6/fe124d79a550d65112b6

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone is still following this thread, but a client recently asked me for something similar. The client wanted new Leads to be assigned to the same Owner as an existing Contact with a matching email address. Standard Salesforce Lead Assignment Rules didn't support this, so I implemented it using Process Builder and Visual Workflow. There was no need to write Apex code.

It was straightforward and reasonably quick to do, so I put together a blog post outlining the steps. Hopefully someone will find this useful in future.

https://alearningdiary.com/2017/11/12/assign-a-lead-in-salesforce-based-on-existing-contact-owner/

Brian